# Timestamp sorting

Tags: python, sorting, timestamp

I have the following data set:

```
Sample  Date Time   Elapsed Time (hr)   Power (V)   Power (mW)  Current (A) Main Temp (degC)    BRF Temp (degC) SHG Temp (degC) THG Temp (degC) Main Temp Drive (volt)  Alt PD (adc)    UV PD (adc) IR PD (adc) DIO0 (hex)  DIO2 (hex)  DIO4 (hex)  DIO5 (hex)  Annotation
1   2/2/2017 9:54:53 PM 0.0002  -1.0000 61.7638 17.5781 24.1796 48.1374 57.0930 56.0887 2.0742  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    Start Pos=BI7, Cmd=60.1mW
2   2/2/2016 9:59:52 PM 0.0833  -1.0000 61.8029 17.4072 23.0301 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 5.1211  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
3   2/2/2016 10:04:50 PM    0.1660  -1.0000 61.8422 17.3584 23.3169 48.0849 57.0398 55.8946 6.1406  813 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
4   2/2/2012 10:09:49 PM    0.2490  -1.0000 61.8531 17.3584 23.2286 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.0820  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
5   2/2/2016 10:14:46 PM    0.3317  -1.0000 61.8662 17.3340 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.1055  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
6   2/2/2015 10:19:44 PM    0.4144  -1.0000 61.8711 17.3096 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8769 6.1289  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
7   2/2/2016 10:24:42 PM    0.4972  -1.0000 61.8675 17.3584 23.2286 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.1289  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
8   2/2/2013 10:29:42 PM    0.5804  -1.0000 61.8754 17.3584 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8769 6.1289  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
9   2/2/2016 10:35:34 PM    0.6782  -1.0000 61.8741 17.3340 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8769 6.1523  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
10  2/2/2016 10:41:22 PM    0.7748  -1.0000 61.8744 17.3584 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.1758  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
11  2/2/2014 10:46:30 PM    0.8606  -1.0000 61.8685 17.4072 23.2286 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.1406  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
12  2/2/2016 10:52:05 PM    0.9535  -1.0000 1.0546  0.0244  23.0742 48.0849 57.0398 55.8946 3.8320  0   -1  -1  D0F5    0F14    F093    FFC4    #
13  2/2/2016 10:57:18 PM    1.0406  -1.0000 61.7084 17.2607 23.1183 48.0849 57.0220 55.8769 8.8242  809 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
14  2/2/2016 11:02:40 PM    1.1300  -1.0000 61.8275 17.3584 23.2507 48.0849 57.0398 55.8946 6.4219  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
15  2/2/2016 11:02:40 PM    1.2193  -1.0000 61.8590 17.3096 23.2728 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.1172  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
16  2/2/2016 11:02:40 PM    1.3089  -1.0000 61.8622 17.2852 23.1845 48.0849 57.0398 55.8946 6.0820  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
17  2/2/2016 11:02:40 PM    1.3981  -1.0000 61.8649 17.2607 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8769 6.1055  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
18  2/2/2016 11:02:40 PM    1.4872  -1.0000 61.8727 17.3340 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.1289  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
19  2/2/2016 11:29:27 PM    1.5764  -1.0000 61.8698 17.3828 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.0938  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
20  2/2/2016 11:34:49 PM    1.6657  -1.0000 61.8741 17.2607 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.1289  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
21  2/2/2016 11:40:12 PM    1.7556  -1.0000 61.8767 17.2607 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8946 6.1055  812 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
22  2/2/2016 11:45:34 PM    1.8450  -1.0000 61.8718 17.2852 23.2065 48.0849 57.0220 55.8769 6.1289  811 -1  -1  D0F2    0F14    F8B1    FFE4    #
```

I have to sort the data in order of timestamp and then remove the duplicate timestamps. New to Python so any help most appreciated!

Thanks,

Jordan.

Comment: Please take a few moments and format your question.  Add four spaces to each line which contains code/data.

Comment: Showing us the output really doesn't help that much.  Show us the code that produces this output.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the library **pandas**.
It is very powerful at data handling and manipulation.
Its also possible to import different formats like CSV, json and much more.

To solve your issue you can import your data into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

After that you can sort your data by the timestamp.
Furthermore to filter duplicates you can use the **groupby** functionality.

```
dfGrouped = df.groupby(columnName)
```

For the groups you can also define what to do like calculating *mean*, *sum*, *min/max* and much more